# Configure SQL-SERVER without running service

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to change the location of the temp.mdf or other files without starting SQL-Server?

I wanted to reactivate an old server but one of it's USB hard disk was been already used somewhere else. Now i'm unable to start the SQL-Server service in Configuration Manager.

The event log has following entry:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   MSSQLSERVER
Event Category: (2)
Event ID:   17207
Date:       30.08.2011
Time:       15:53:10
User:       N/A
Computer:   SQLSERV
Description:
```

> FCB::Open: Betriebssystemfehler 3(error not found) beim Erstellen oder
>   Öffnen der Datei 'M:\temp.mdf'. Diagnostizieren und korrigieren Sie
>   den Betriebssystemfehler, und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.

[Here are informations on this error.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=SQL%20Server&ProdVer=2000.80.760.0&EvtID=17207&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&LCID=1033)

**Q:** So how can i change the location of database files that reference non existing drives without having SQL-SERVER service started? I haven't seen an option in Configuration-Manager. Or is there some kind of "safe-mode" in SQL-Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming it is not just your temp.mdf, but all your other system databases that are missing as well...

There is a kind of safe mode, it's called `"master-only recovery mode"`. Whether you can use it depends on whether you have a backup of your databases from your missing hard drive.

If you have a backup of your database instance "data" folder, then [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408(v=SQL.90).aspx) has some useful information in the "***Failure Recovery Procedure***" section. I would also look at the section "***Moving the master and Resource Databases***". Are you able to follow the steps in this without sql server started?

If not, you could play with the [startup options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737(v=SQL.90).aspx). The sql server process has startup options to specify an alternate master database location. You can also change the the startup options in the registry here: `HKLM\Software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\MSSQL.1\mssqlserver\parameters`
(assuming this is the first or only database instance you have installed).

If you **don't** have a backup of the data folder, then you should look at [rebuilding the master database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143269(v=sql.90).aspx), which involves running the sql server setup again using the log of your original installation.

EDIT: Is it just the tempdb on the missing hard disk? If so you may be able to enter master only recovery mode and move the temp database as described in the [first link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408(v=SQL.90).aspx) under "***Failure Recovery Procedure***" steps 1-2. Then follow the example of how to move the tempdb at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can, except a special start-up sequence called master-only I believe. It's where the user databases aren't mounted, and I believe TempDB isn't created.

Is it possible to temporarily present a M: drive, with suitable permissions.... so you get SQL Server running, and then change the TempDB location to something that will work permanently?

System databases - Master only.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408(v=SQL.100).aspx